# rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I am using the **GKE v1.14.10-gke.27+** with **Istio (v1.2.10-gke.3)** add-on. I have 2 golang apps (client & server) with gRPC.
I am getting the following error on the client app when I use **mTLS with strict mode**.

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
```

I am not getting this error on the **GKE v1.17.5-gke.0** which has **Istio v1.4.6-gke.0**

Comment: Could you try to change your service names as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/)? What if you change mtls to permissive? Maybe try to add destination rules with mutual tls as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule)? As [support](https://istio.io/news/support/announcing-1.2-eol/) for istio 1.2 ended on December 13th, 2019 there might be issues which were not fixed. I would recommend to go with the 1.4.6 as there is no problem with that error.

Comment: Hi @jt97, I have already added the name in service as mentioned in the link but still not working. These applications communicate with each other & calls some RestAPIs. There is no inbound traffic from the outside cluster.

Comment: If you could check if that works on permissive tls then we would have information if this error is about mtls, if it works on permissive then it's problem with strict. If it's problem with strict I would recommend you  to configure Envoy to use mTLS when sending requests to other services in the mesh. This can be achieved by creating a DestinationRule. Take a look [here](https://maistra.io/docs/examples/mesh-wide_mtls/).